# Is there a way to format numbers' font in Nexus One/Nexus S?

Tags: automation, fonts, formatting

I love to see numbers in Georgia font and would love to see them auto-formatted into that font! If you know such tips, please share!

*Update*

I want just numbers to be formatted while other texts remain as-is.

Answer (score 5):

Android stores its fonts at /system/fonts/ using TTF (TrueType) format. If you have a program that can edit TTF files (e.g. FontForge), you can replace the number fonts in these .ttf files with your preferred number fonts to change the glyph used for numbers globally. If you're rooted, you should be able to replace these font files with your own modified version.

Note that I have never tried this, note as well that some applications' layout may rely on the system fonts being of a particular size or shape, and this modifications may break the layout in those applications.